# Capistrano Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano, bitbucket

This is my situation: I have this rails app that I have "capified" and I'm trying to deploy with capistrano onto my Ubuntu cloud server. I have been following this guide -> http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano

When I run `$ cap production deploy`, cap aborts and I get the result `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed`.

My guess: My server is not getting access to my bitbucket repo?

Well I have generated an ssh key on my server, added the key in my bitbucket account and also done a `git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:my-username/my-repo.git`.

So what am I missing here?

Here's my config/deploy.rb: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7707266

Comment: did you try connecting to all used servers? is it possible to git clone from your production server? do you have agent-forwarding enabled?

Comment: @phoet 1: how do you mean? 2: Yes, I can git clone from my server, but I have to enter password for key(!). 3: yes I have.

Comment: it has to work without a password. you need to have all public keys set up correctly in authorized keys file and on github.

Comment: @phoet: Hi, would you know if public keys need to be setup to run any task? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my dev computer could not access the production server. It turned out I had put the line `server "<server-ip>", user: "depoy-user", roles: %w{web app}` in config/deploy.rb. Moving it into config/deploy/production.rb solved my problem. Facepalms, facepalms everywhere.